# Flex: container scrollbars in HBox

Tags: apache-flex, scrollbar, scroll, hbox

I have an HBox in my flex application. The problem is, when there are too many things inside the HBox a scroll bar appears at the bottom of the app. How can I make it appear in the HBox, so the scrollbar only scrolls thestuff inside the HBox and not the entire app?

Comment: A small piece of friendly advice: make use of the 'comments' section when replying to posts.  Don't create new answers when responding: people might think you're trolling for rep points (even though you're new and you're obviously not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating a Canvas around the HBox. If you declare the width of the Canvas to 100%, it should be the width of the stage, and when the HBox inside gets wider, a scrollbar should appear.

Comment: Niko, That works!
BTW I needed the horizontalAlign in case there aren't enough items to fully populate the entire width of the HBox. The way you change it is `myHBox.setStyle ("horizontalAlign", "center");`

Answer (score 1):

```
<Application 
xmlns="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
horizontalScrollPolicy="off">
    <HBox width="100%">
    ...
```

I believe that should work.